# Sorting data just by one nth column

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

I have a file with two columnns, strings in the first one and numbers in the second. I want to sort file by the second column. If there are equal values in two lines, I dont want to sort them by the first column, but I want the original order to remain. This is a simple example:

```
BBB:100
CCC:200 
GGG:150
AAA:200
```

When I use `sort -t: -k2 -n` I get this:

```
BBB:100
GGG:150
AAA:200
CCC:200
```

But what I want is:

```
BBB:100
GGG:150
CCC:200
AAA:200
```

Is there something that could help me? thanks

Comment: --stable (man is your friend).

Comment: I didnt notice that in man, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) sort. Use the `-s` or `--stable` switch.